# Annotation - how to add field level annotation in Java dynamically

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, spring-annotations

Imagine there is class

```
public class sample {
   private String fieldName;
}
```

Which already compiled and the part of the claspath when the jam statsup.

I want add `@notnull` and `@size(min=1,max=5)` dynamically for `fieldName`(not class level)

Any suggestions plz

Comment: Did you try using bytecode manipulating library like ByteBuddy, Javassist, ASM or, CGLib?

Comment: Yes . Not able to set annotation if it fine could you plz share a code??

Comment: You can't (or at least really shouldn't) add validation rules like that. Instead, you can supply the rules externally though an [XML file](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2137346/data-storage/java-tip-hibernate-validation-in-a-standalone-implementation.html).
 There's a tutorial here. See the bottom of page 1 and start of page 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the question as a ByteBuddy question, without the synopsis of validation.

Using ByteBuddy, you can change your classes at runtime. But in certain conditions, like you are not on Android (Dalvik's virtual machine is different than ordinary JVMs), and you shouldn't change an already loaded class.

```
class Subclass {
    public void func() {

    }
}

class FunctionalInterfaceImpl implements FunctionalInterface {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return FunctionalInterface.class;
    }
}

public class TryingByteBuddy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(TypePool.Default.ofClassPath().describe("com.experiments.Subclass").resolve(),
                    ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath())
            .annotateType(new FunctionalInterfaceImpl())
            .make()
            .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(new Subclass().getClass().getAnnotations()));
    }

}
```

In this code `Subclass` is a class that doesn't have the @FunctionalInterface annotation. Now when you run you will find it has it.

NOTES ON THIS CODE:

> 1. You will find that we didn't use `Subclass.class` when trying to redefine the class
>
>    > This is *to prevent loading of the class before creating the alternative*
>    >
>    > Using `Subclass.class` will invoke the class loader to load the original class, this prevents ByteBuddy from doing its work
> 2. We "implemented" the annotation interface we want to add (`FunctionalInterface` in this example).

For more info:

[ByteBuddy tutorial](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial)

Comment: No this works for method level annotation but I am looking for variable level annotation with existing object